# Carrito de compras class constructora JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class

Esta es mi 2da pregunta en este medio, en la primera que hice fue abrumadora la cantidad de respuestas y lo que aprendí gracias a ellas asi que muchas gracias por si alguno me recuerda.

En esta ocasion estoy teniendo otro problemilla. Estoy haciendo un curso de JavaScript en el cual estoy haciendo un carrito de compras como proyecto. Les paso el link de la ultima versión justo antes de intentar esto por si tienen algun consejo que darme :) https://danielmedina-jscoderhouse.netlify.app/

En principio el carrito como tal lo tenia definido como un array, pero ahora se me esta pidiendo lo convierta en un objeto y use clases constructoras, pero la verdad me ha costado muchisimo y ya tengo varios días en esto y no puedo hacerlo funcionar. Les paso el carrito que quiero convertir y hacer funcionar pero ahora con class:

```
let carrito = []

//AGREGAR AL CARRITO

let carritoLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('carrito'))//Se recupera lo que haya dentro del carrito al refrescar la página

if (carritoLS) {  //Si había algo al refrescar la página, entonces carrito será = a lo que haya en el LS y se ejecuta la funcion agregarAlCarrito para que lo muestre
    carrito = carritoLS
    actualizarCarrito()
}


function agregarAlCarrito(id) {
    
    const productoElegido = productos.find(el => el.id === id) //Se indica que lo elegido tomará el valor del id seleccionado

    if (productoElegido) {
        carrito.push(productoElegido) //Se ingresa al carrito
    }
    actualizarCarrito() //Se actualiza con lo que tenga

    localStorage.setItem('carrito', JSON.stringify(carrito)) //Se guarda en el local lo seleccionado. Al refrescar toma lo que habia y comienza a agregar si el usuario elige mas productos
}

//ELIMINAR PRODUCTO

function eliminarProducto(id) {
    const quitarProducto = carrito.find(el => el.id == id)
    const indice = carrito.indexOf(quitarProducto)
    carrito.splice(indice, 1)
    
    localStorage.setItem('carrito', JSON.stringify(carrito))
    actualizarCarrito()
}

//ACTUALIZAR CARRITO

function actualizarCarrito() { //Para actualizar con lo que se elija y anexe al modal
    
    const contenedorCarrito = document.getElementById('contenedor-carrito')
    
    const precioTotal = document.getElementById('precio-total')
    const precioIva = document.getElementById('precio-iva')
    const precioPagar = document.getElementById('aPagar')
    const contadorCarrito = document.getElementById('contador-carrito')

    contenedorCarrito.innerHTML = ''

    carrito.forEach((producto) => {
        contenedorCarrito.innerHTML += `
        <div class="producto-carrito">
            <p>${producto.desc}</p>
            <p>Precio: $${producto.precio}</p>
            <button onclick=eliminarProducto(${producto.id}) class="boton-eliminar"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </div>
    
        `
    })
    
    let sumaProductos = carrito.reduce((acum, el) => acum += el.precio, 0)
    let ivaProductos = carrito.reduce((acum, el) => acum += el.precio * 0.21, 0)
    
    precioTotal.innerText = sumaProductos.toFixed(2)
    precioIva.innerText = ivaProductos.toFixed(2)
    precioConDecimal = sumaProductos + ivaProductos
    precioPagar.innerText = precioConDecimal.toFixed(2)
    localStorage.setItem('precioConDecimal', JSON.stringify(precioConDecimal))
    

    contadorCarrito.innerText = carrito.length
    localStorage.setItem('contadorCarrito', JSON.stringify(carrito.length))
}

function eliminarTodo() {
    localStorage.clear(carrito)
    carrito = []
    actualizarCarrito()
}
```

El resto del codigo que no copié es solo la parte del filtrado de productos, el modal, y el stock con los productos que no creo sean necesarios para esto

Ante todo muchisimas gracias por la predisposición. Saludos

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el problema en concreto? Te refieres a una Clase y a algún problema con el constructor, pero no veo ninguna Clase en tu código. Considera agregar siempre un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable en la misma pregunta. Por cierto, ¿leíste la [documentación sobre las Clases](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) en JS?

Comment: Hola. Si capaz no me expresé bien. Tengo ese carrito de compras que copié en el código. Me mandaron a convertirlo en un objeto con class constructora, pero la verdad lo he intentado y no he podido. Lo subi asi como array porque nada de lo que intente al convertirlo en objeto me funcionó. Lo subí así para que vieran lo que tengo

Comment: Realmente la pregunta no es muy clara. Si te piden que diseñes una clase `Carrito` te están pidiendo que diseñes una entidad que represente a un `Carrito` en tu modelo de datos. Ese objeto (Carrito) podrá tener diferentes tipos de propiedades: cadenas, números, arrays e incluso otros objetos (clases, estructuras, etc) así como métodos y podrá o no extender de otros objetos. Lee el enlace anterior que te abre la puerta un poco al mundo de las clases y luego si no entiendes algo mejora la pregunta indicando lo que has intentado. Aquí ni siquiera has diseñado tu clase.

Comment: Aaah perfecto. Muchisimas gracias. Lo leeré con calma e intentaré con eso. Si necesito mas que nada un poco de orientación teórica me parece.